# Legacy Google Droid Sans Fonts CentOS7 download

Tags: fonts, centos7, android-fonts

I have a linux rendering engine and while rendering some of the characters in the documents, it was shown as squared boxes. It all seemed to work fine in the sample application I was running on my Android Device and debugging it, I found that the font DroidSansFallback.ttf was responsible for finding the matching glyphs for those characters. I tried installing the google droid sans fonts using `yum install google-droid-sans-fonts`. Also, tried directly installing the rpm from http://pkgs.org/centos-7/atrpms-x86_64/google-droid-sans-fonts-20100409-1.noarch.rpm.html. But the characters were still not being rendered. I saw there was a significant different in the size of DroidSansFallback.ttf files. On my Nexus 3, it was around 4.8 MB, while yum installed one had the size of 3.2 MB. I simply copied the ttf file from my Nexus 3 device over to the linux machine in `/usr/share/fonts/` and the characters started rendering fine. 
Is there a way I could get this specific version or older versions of Droid Sans Fonts installed on my CentOS server? Is there any google's archived repository where I can get them?

One of the links where it seems to be available is: https://code.google.com/p/galaxy-nexus-khmer/downloads/detail?name=DroidSansFallback.ttf

Answer (score 0):

Well you have the reason why the centos font is older. Google was helpful in open-sourcing Droid (thank you Google, that was mightily nice!) but its font publication methods are horrible. You have to comb thousands of Android code dumps, each several gigabytes in size, and mashed up from hundreds of git repos, just in case they include an updated version of of a font file less than 10 MiB. Rince and repeat, it gets old fast. Good ISP download test though.

(I created the Fedora/Centos package a few years back).